# Universal and existential quantification using C++ template magic

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, quantifiers

Is there a way to implement [universal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification) and [existential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification) quantification using C++ template magic (maybe using SFINAE etc.)? Something like this:

```
template
    <
        template <typename Argument> class Predicate
    >
struct UniversalQuantification
{
    static const bool value =
        /*for any Argument Predicate<Argument>::value == true ? true : false*/;
};

template
    <
        template <typename Argument> class Predicate
    >
struct ExistentialQuantification
{
    static const bool value =
        /*for some Argument Predicate<Argument>::value == true ? true : false*/;
};
```

Comment: I believe this is simply not possible. What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: @iavr This time it is a *purely* theoretical question. But I'll be happy to see all possible solutions, even non-ideal and approximate. I hope that there is at least some decision.

Comment: How should these quantifications be used?

Comment: @nosid Suppose you have a class template with one type parameter: `template <typename> class Predicate;` which has a static field `static const bool value;` (possibly its values are different for different template arguments). You want to check at a compile time that `value` is true for all possible `Predicate` template arguments (universal quantification). Or there exists at least one argument for which `value` is true (existential quantification).

Comment: At runtime possible, at compile-time impossible IMO

Comment: So the question is, if the predicate is _true_ for **all** types? The number of types is infinite, and not all types are known at compile-time. So, that's impossible.

Comment: @Paranaix It is not interesting at run-time.

Comment: @nosid The number of types is **not** infinite, but it's large enough :-)

Comment: @nosid If you say about universal quantification then yes, you are right. Predicate should be true for all types. All types in C++ are known at compile-time and their quantity is not infinite, of course. :-)

Comment: @Constructor So do you suggest we begin instantiating with a number of types to see what happens? Would we then need to enumerate all types present in the current compilation unit? Would you allow any constraints that may limit the number?

Comment: @iavr Solutions with all possible reasonable constraints are welcome, too.

Comment: @Constructor: At compile-time, you only see the types of the same compilation unit, but there can be further types in different compilation units. And regarding the number of types: With `template <int...> struct Ints { };`, you already have a centillion different types.

Comment: @nosid Yes, I think it is sufficient to restrict the problem to the types from the same compilation unit. And centillion is not infinity.

Comment: ExistentialQuantification is very tied to the halting problem...

Comment: @MooingDuck Well, as a constraint we could exclude testing "smart" functions like `UniversalQuantification` and `ExistentialQuantification` themselves :-) Not that it's much easier now!

Comment: @Constructor: In many cases, the number of types is theoretically infinite (it's not at all hard to define `succ` in TMP), and only bounded by the template recursion depth.  But if you have types right up to the limit of template recursion, you can't pass all those types to another template for consideration...

Comment: @MooingDuck Template parameter of `ExistentialQuantification` class template is a class template with a *type* parameter. So I don't understand why the halting problem is tied to it.

Comment: @BenVoigt We all use computers with finite memory so all theoretical infinities become finite at practice. I think we can assume that the quantity of types is not big enough to allow the occurrence of the problems with the limit of template recursion.

Comment: @Constructor You can wrap a `template<template<typename>class> struct` like `UniversalQuantification` inside a `template<typename> struct`, and a `template<typename> struct` like any predicate inside a plain `struct`. Then `UniversalQuantification` behaves like an ordinary predicate, and the halting problem applies.

Comment: @iavr Do you mean something like `template <typename Argument> struct Wrapper { static const bool value = ExistentialQuantification<Wrapper>::value; };`?

Comment: @Constructor It's large, but here it is: `template<template<typename>class pred> struct tmp { template<typename T> using map = pred<T>; };`. Then `template<typename pred_class> struct universal { static const bool value = pred_class::template map<any_type>::value; };` where of course `any_type` is `universal`'s magic. Then you try `universal<tmp<pred> >`.

Answer (score 3):

If you pass a **finite** set of possible template arguments to the template, it is indeed possible to evaluate this at compile-time. However, it is impossible to evaluate this for every argument the passed template has been used with, as these types/args are unknown.

This is the solution for a finite set of arguments for the `ExistentialQuantification` class. In order to achieve the behaviour of the `UniversalQuantification` class, you simple have to change the `||` to a `&&`:

```
template<typename Arg>
struct Pred1;

template<>
struct Pred1<float> { static const bool value = true; };

template<>
struct Pred1<double> { static const bool value = false; };

template<>
struct Pred1<long> { static const bool value = true; };


template<template <typename Argument> class Predicate, typename... Types>
struct ExistentialQuantification;

template<template <typename Argument> class Predicate, typename Arg>
struct ExistentialQuantification<Predicate, Arg>
{
    static const bool value = Predicate<Arg>::value;
};

template<template <typename Argument> class Predicate, typename Arg, typename... Types>
struct ExistentialQuantification<Predicate, Arg, Types...>
{
    static const bool value = Predicate<Arg>::value || ExistentialQuantification<Predicate, Types...>::value;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << ExistentialQuantification<Pred1, long, double, float>::value << std::endl;
}
```

In this example, `value` will evaluate to `true || false || true` and is thus true of course.

Comment: Thank you. It is an obvious solution for a finite set of types. And you forgot a semicolon after `template<> struct Pred1<long>` specialization.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, if we're just being smart here, and if we're allowed a couple of constraints, here are two constraints on the programmer, that really solve the problem, smoothly.

1. if a predicate is needed in the code that is always true, only use the following:

   `template<typename> struct always : std::true_type { };`
2. if a predicate is needed in the code that is never true, only use the following:

   `template<typename> struct never : std::false_type { };`

Now, the solution is simple:

```
template<template<typename> class>
struct UniversalQuantification : std::false_type { };

template<>
struct UniversalQuantification<always> : std::true_type { };

template<template<typename> class>
struct ExistentialQuantification : std::true_type { };

template<>
struct ExistentialQuantification<never> : std::false_type { };
```

Comment: You did what I ordered but not what I wanted. :-)

Comment: Oh, maybe that's why I wrote "if we're just being smart here" :-)

Comment: Why didn't you use `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Using a library like [**Boost.MPL**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual.html), if you can put your universe of allowed types into a type list, e.g. in a `boost::mpl::vector`, then your quantifiers are just the compile-time version of `std::all_of` and `std::any_of`. You can define them as:

```
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>                  // is_same, is_base_of
#include <boost/mpl/end.hpp>            // end
#include <boost/mpl/find_if.hpp>        // find_if
#include <boost/mpl/lambda.hpp>         // lambda
#include <boost/mpl/logical.hpp>        // not_
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>   // _1
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>         // vector

template<typename Sequence, typename Pred>
struct all_of
:
        std::is_same< typename
                boost::mpl::find_if<
                        Sequence,
                        boost::mpl::not_<Pred>
                >::type, typename
                boost::mpl::end<Sequence>::type
        >
{};

template<typename Sequence, typename Pred>
struct none_of
:
        all_of< Sequence, boost::mpl::not_< Pred > >
{};

template<typename Sequence, typename Pred>
struct any_of
:
        boost::mpl::not_< none_of< Sequence, Pred > >
{};

struct B {}; 
struct D : B {};
struct X {};

using Universe = boost::mpl::vector<B, D, X>;
using Predicate = boost::mpl::lambda<std::is_base_of<B, boost::mpl::_1>>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << all_of<Universe, Predicate>{} << "\n";
    std::cout << any_of<Universe, Predicate>{} << "\n";
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b088cb520a75fd10).

As you can see, because `X` does not have `B` as a base class, the universal quantification fails, but because `D` does have `B` as a base class, the existential quantification succeeds.

Comment: Thank you. I think it will take time to realize this solution. Is this solution equivalent to the solution using C++11 variadic templates (possibly involving `std::tuple`)?

Comment: @Constructor modified my example to work live on Coliru. I would not recommend rolling your own. Boost.MPL is a very nice library once you get the hang of it, and it works even with C++98.

Comment: Thank you for the example. Boost is a very nice library, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if we're just talking about n-ary (variadic) functions **and**, **or** as in the answer by [TemplateRex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22644199/2644390), here's my preferred way without Boost:

```
using _true  = std::integral_constant <bool, true>;
using _false = std::integral_constant <bool, false>;

template <bool C, typename T, typename E>
using _if = typename std::conditional <C, T, E>::type;

template <typename...> struct _and;
template <typename...> struct _or;

template <typename A, typename... B>
struct _and <A, B...> : _if <A{}, _and <B...>, _false> { };

template <typename A, typename... B>
struct _or <A, B...> : _if <A{}, _true, _or <B...> > { };

template <> struct _and <> : _true { };
template <> struct _or <> : _false { };
```

Comment: Why do you not use `std::conditional` instead of your `_if_t` class template? And I don't see any predicate template in your solution. :-)

Comment: Right, see edited code (it was just a matter of habit, doing everything from scratch!) You don't see a predicate template because it's only part of a solution :-) It doesn't matter, I'm preparing another solution now.

Comment: I'm looking forward to it.